# Mhchem overfull boxes

Tags: line-breaking, mhchem

I am using the `mhchem` package in-line and the equations don't break lines and thus cause overfull boxes. Any way to force them to follow the rules for line breaks.

i.e. the following sentence:

```
Clays exist in groups with generalised formulae, these include: 
the smectite group \ce{(A1/3D2-3[T4O10]Z2.nH2O)} and the serpentine group 
\ce{(D2[Si2O5](OH4)\pm nH2O)} among others.
```

the formulae comes out lovely looking it just hangs over the margin. .  .

Comment: You'll have to break this up yourself: `mhchem` does not do this itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions get boxed, but if you shake the box a bit it will break around the math binary operators. (I don't know if this is entirely safe for all mhchem constructs but works here at least to break on the `\pm`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\makeatletter


\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\xce@main}[1]{%
  \bgroup%
  \ifnum 1<\mhchem@option@version%
    \ifmmode\else\def\mhchem@option@alwaystextmode{1}\fi%
  \fi%
  \def\bond{}\def\sbond{}\def\dbond{}\def\tbond{}%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty\else%
    \ifmmode\else\mhchem@option@textFont\fi%
    \ensuremath{\break%
      \mhchem@ce@xx#1 \mhchem@END\mhchem@ENDEND%
    \break}%
  \fi%
  \egroup%
}%

\def\xce#1{{%
\let\ce@main\xce@main
\setbox0\vbox{%
\hsize\maxdimen
\ce{#1}%
\par
\setbox0\lastbox
\unskip
\unpenalty
\setbox0\lastbox
\global\setbox1\hbox{\unhbox0\unskip\unskip\unpenalty}%
\global\setbox1\hbox{\unhbox1 \global\setbox3\lastbox}%
}%
\unhbox3 }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Clays exist in groups with generalised formulae, these include: the smectite group \ce{(A1/3D2-3[T4O10]Z2.nH2O)} and the serpentine group \ce{(D2[Si2O5](OH4)\pm nH2O)} among others.

Clays exist in groups with generalised formulae, these include: the smectite group \xce{(A1/3D2-3[T4O10]Z2.nH2O)} and the serpentine group \xce{(D2[Si2O5](OH4)\pm nH2O)} among others.





\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I did find (by chance a simples way) the chemformula package (which is loaded with chemmacros) stays away from math mode so the equations automatically break :-D

Comment: Oh well: I had fun making the answer anyway;-)